# Non-finite verb forms function

Tags: participles, nonfinite-verbs

Could anyone please tell the functions of the bolded participles (*raising, saying* and *displaying*) in the following examples?

1. ...and has continued with parliamentary duties this week, ***raising*** the possibility that he may have infected others. [[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/mar/27/nonchalant-boris-johnson-accused-of-covid-19-complacency)]
2. Not long afterwards, Hancock issued his own statement ***saying*** he too had tested positive. [ibid.]
3. Prof Whitty, who had advised the prime minister to get tested, said he too was ***displaying*** symptoms. [ibid.]

Comment: I assume you mean grammatical functions. In 1. "raising" is **predicator**(i.e. head) of the verb phrase "raising the possibility ...", which is functioning as predicate in a clause in adjunct function. The clause has a resultative meaning.In 2. "saying" is predicator in the verb phrase/clause "saying he had tested positive", which is a gerund-participial clause modifying "statement".  In 3. "displacing"  is complement of "was" in a progressive aspect verb phrase heading the clause "was displaying symptons".

Comment: @BillJ Good question! I assumed it was about semantic functions...

Answer (score 2):

> [1] ..*.and has continued with parliamentary duties this week,* [*raising*
> *the possibility that he may have infected others*].
>
> [2] *Not long afterwards, Hancock issued his own statement* [*saying he*
> *too had tested positive*].
>
> [3] *Prof Whitty, who had advised the prime minister to get tested,*
> *said* [*he too was displaying symptoms*].

I assume you mean grammatical functions, in which case I'm inclined to say:

In [1] "raising" is **predicator** (i.e. head) in the bracketed clause -- an adjunct with a resultative interpretation (note that "thus" could be added, as in "thus raising the possibility ..."

In [2] "saying" is **predicator** in the bracketed clause, functioning as modifier of "statement". The meaning is similar to the relative clause "which said he too had tested positive".

In 3. "displaying"  is **predicator** in the clause "displaying symptoms", functioning  as complement of "was" in the bracketed progressive aspect clause.

I think!

Answer (score 0):

In "raising the possibility...", *raising* is a participle fronting a reduced relative clause = "**which raises** the possibility..."

"saying he too had tested positive." *saying* is a participle in a free modifier (This modifies the whole of the main clause.)

"said he too was displaying symptoms." Please think about this yourself - isn't it obvious that it is part of the continuous form of the verb?

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, "raising" is the verbal form in the past participle phrase "raising the possibility that he may have infected others", which is a  non restrictive participial phrase: it adds more information ([ref.](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-participial-phrases)) and this is so because of the comma after "week" (see ref. again).

In the second sentence, "saying" is also such a form with respect to  "saying he too had tested positive", a participial phrase that is, according to the same reference, restrictive, this being so as there is no comma after "statement".

In the third sentence there is not a participial phrase in the terms "displaying symptoms"; "displaying" is part of the verbal construction "was displaying", which is a progressive form, and "symptoms" is the object of this form, not the object of "displaying".